Why does this BMS have a large discharging resistor value of 480 ohms?
I am creating a Battery Management System (BMS) for my lipo battery. I found a BMS online (Here is the link) and it has "cell balancing" with a 480 ohm resistor. This means that when the battery cell has a voltage greater than 4.2 volts it will turn on a MOSFET to discharge that one cell which balances all the cells to have equal voltage to prevent damage to the battery.
So if the battery cell has a voltage of 4.2 volts which triggers the discharging MOSFET to turn on, then the total amps leaving this cell would be 4.2 V / 480 ohms = 8.75 mA. Now I am not exactly sure what the charging current is, but I would imagine there would be around 2 amps for most LIPO batteries being charged into the battery cells.
My question is how does this very small discharge current of 8.75 mA have any effect on the overall voltage of the battery cell when compared to the 2 amps that is charging the battery cell? The 2 Amps charging the battery is a little over 200 times more charge than the 8.75 mA being discharged. This makes me think that even if the discharging MOSFET is turned on then the battery cell would still continue to charge because 8.75 mA is almost nothing when compared to the 2 Amps flowing into the battery cell. Can someone help me understand why they picked a resistor value of 480 ohms?
Here is a picture of the circuit:

P.S for some reason the schematic doesn't show the resistor values, but in the article it says it is 480 ohms. "the MOSFET connects a low resistance path through this 480-ohm resistance which acts as a load resistor and starts depleting the battery".

A great question.  Your circuit does not show the charging circuit, so we can't say if the 480 ohm value is 'correct'.  Each cell is charged with either Icharge or Icharge-Idischarge.  Icharge being the charger current, Idischarge being the current through the 480ohm resistor.  The proper value of I discharge depends on both Icharge but also the assumed mismatch in battery capacity, which is unstated in this schematic.  That information is needed to select an Idischarge that will correct any imbalance between the series battery cells.

Basically you are asking about the article. Like most articles like this, they may be just clickbaits for hobbyists, and may contain errors, even made by non-technical editorial people. For example, there is no indication from where the 480 ohms comes into the article. There is no such resistor in the photos, so who knows what else might be wrong in the article. The 480 ohms is not even a value in any of the standard resistor  series.
